# Python 3 UnicodeDecodeError in Bottle

Tags: python-3.x, cmd, windows-10, bottle

Can't run hello world application from Bottle site http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/:

```python
from bottle import route, run, template

@route('/hello/<name>')
def index(name):
    return template('<b>Hello {{name}}</b>!', name=name)

run(host='localhost', port=8080)
```

when I run the code, I got a message: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xcc in position 0: invalid continuation byte

[image: output]

I use Python3 and Bottle at Windows10.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following in the first line of your code

```
#encoding: utf-8
```

This is required if you use strings with unicode data like *Olé*, *Aló* and so...

Also I recommend you to review for strange characters in your code.